# Recived different fix message in fromApp method and message file in filStorePath

Tags: java, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am trying to capture `MarketDataIncrementalRefresh` messages.
It got a group `noMDEntries`, I am trying to parse over it.

I have two problems:

1st - I have printed the message that is coming in the `fromApp` method which is different from what I am getting in my file created through `FileStorePath`.
How is this possible? Then I am cracking through `message cracker` but even after cracking it is the same message as received in `fromApp`

Message from `fromApp`:

`8=FIX.4.29=7535=X34=3649=XXXXXXXX52=2019011605:09:51.00056=XXXXXXXX262=1268=110=223`

Message received in file :

```
8=FIX.4.29=0019435=X49=XXXXXXXX56=XXXXXXXX34=3652=20190116-05:09:51.000262=1268=1279=1269=055=ES167=FUT200=201903541=20190315205=1518211=M207=CME100=XCME461=F15=USD270=249375271=20290=110=123
```

2nd - While iterating through the group I am getting an error as :

```
quickfix.FieldNotFound: 268, index=1
    at quickfix.FieldMap.getGroup(FieldMap.java:633)
```

but as you can see field 268 is set, also I have checked it again through `message.isSetField(268)` which results in `true`, just after it tried :

```
MarketDataIncrementalRefresh.NoMDEntries mdEntriesGroup = new MarketDataIncrementalRefresh.NoMDEntries();
message.getGroup(1, mdEntriesGroup);
```

it gives the above error.

FIX42.xml looks like which has same order of fields as in my message received.:

```
 <message name='MarketDataIncrementalRefresh' msgtype='X' msgcat='app'>
        <field name='MDReqID' required='Y' />
        <field name='PriceFeedStatus' required='N' />
        <group name='NoMDEntries' required='Y'>
            <field name='MDUpdateAction' required='Y' />
            <field name='MDEntryType' required='Y' />
            <field name='Symbol' required='N' />
            <field name='SecurityType' required='N' />
            <field name='SecuritySubType' required='N' />
            <field name='MaturityMonthYear' required='N' />
            <field name='MaturityDate' required='N' />
            <field name='MaturityDay' required='N' />
            <field name='PutOrCall' required='N' />
            <field name='StrikePrice' required='N' />
            <field name='OptAttribute' required='N' />
            <field name='DeliveryTerm' required='N' />
            <field name='DeliveryDate' required='N' />
            <field name='SecurityID' required='N' />
            <field name='SecurityExchange' required='N' />
            <field name='ExDestination' required='N' />
            <field name='CFICode' required='N' />
            <field name='Currency' required='N' />
            <field name='MDEntryPx' required='N' />
            <field name='MDEntrySize' required='N' />
            <field name='MDEntryDate' required='N' />
            <field name='MDEntryTime' required='N' />
            <field name='MDEntryPositionNo' required='N' />
            <field name='SecondaryOrderID' required='N' />
            <field name='NumberOfOrders' required='N' />
        </group>
        <field name='ExchangeSendingTime' required='N' />
        <field name='ExchangeTransactTime' required='N' />
        <field name='ExchangeSeqNum' required='N' />
    </message>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always trust the message log over `FromApp()` and `FromAdmin()`.  The log is recorded before the engine attempts to parse the message; the callbacks happen after.  If an error happens in parsing (like in your case), what you see in the callback will be wrong (which you are seeing).

I've seen your issue before.  What is probably happening is that your configuration has a mistake, or your configured DD xml file does not accurately match your counterparty's specification.

**First**, your config file should have these lines:

```
UseDataDictionary=Y

# for FIX4
DataDictionary=path/to/your/dd.xml

# for FIX5+
AppDataDictionary=path/to/your/FIX5whatever.xml
TransportDataDictionary=path/to/your/FIXT1.1.xml
```

**Second**, check your message against the DD file that's in your config.  Probably something in the repeating group definition is not correct.  For instance, a field could be missing from the group definition and the parser is exiting the group early when it hits it.  Make sure your config points to the correct xml file.

(If you fix your message paste above to include visible field separators, I'll come back and help take a look.)

Comment: I was using AppDataDictionary because earlier I was using FIXT1.1, replacing it with DataDictionary worked. Thanks a lot for understanding the issue and providing such useful information.

Comment: Heh, I completely forgot about the FIX5+ config keys.  Updated the answer for that.